# How to see our shop URL in webkul magento extension

Tags: magento, subdomain, multisite

How to build sub-domain like magento multi-vendor site from webkul i unable to access shop url

Comment: Please provide more details

Comment: You can rewrite the url from the seller panel using http://webkul.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/URL.png